# which blog platform to use for multiple bloggers

Tags: installation, wordpress

I want to have a blog for my (small) company where each employee will have his own personal blog. Something like:

http://johndoe.blog.mycompany.com

Is there a good platform to do that? I searched Wordpress and TypePad but couldn't find that feature. Basically what I found is that those blogging platforms are meant to provide only one blog where several users can share (as subscribers/writers/moderators). But I couldn't find a way to split that into several different blogs, but still under the same blog installation/platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wordpress MU](http://mu.wordpress.org/) (Mutliuser) is what you need

Comment: looks like we're both new in here... I'll look into it, but it sounds like a winner! thanks!

Comment: I've been using Wordpress as a blogging tool for a while now. I absolutely love it. I'm not really that good with PHP, but I've managed to even use it for external websites, to get an idea just how much you can customize it check out http://www.mjleppan.com - notice this is a wordpress site, didn't think so heh?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any blog these days supports multiple users very well.  It's really hard to go wrong with Wordpress.

You may want to consider other requirements, such as spam blocking, ease-of-use and ease-of-maintenance.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is fashionable to bash it these days, but Blogger has a very simple interface that most people can get to do what they want, and the 'blogs can be attached to custom DNS names.